# Deployed Angular dist/ on Azure Web App showing me default screen

Tags: angular, azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service

I have setup CI-CD on Azure DevOps using classical editor .I did managed to Build angular by Build Pipeline and  Using Release pipelines I have pushed the Angular /dist folder to the web app.

The contents are in the following :

`/home/site/wwwroot/my-angular-app/`

But whenever I open url for the web-app I only could see default web-page of azure web app.
I have deployed on Web App (Linux) and I have choose Node as runtime task.

As I'm new to Azure Is there anything else needs to done ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you add to question your YAML file?

Comment: I have used classical editor to build pipeline @Krzysztof

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Deployed Angular dist/ on Azure Web App showing me default screen

There are two things you need to do to make the Angular Web App page show when access to https://{appservice_name}.azurewebsites.net.

1. When deploy the Angular /dist folder to azure web app, please don’t
   include the my-angular-app folder. Just let the content of dist
   folder under the path `/home/site/wwwroot`
2. Add `npx serve -s` as Startup Command for your `App Service` > `General settings`:

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks..but i'm getting error like 'Requested path could not be found" I don't weather it's released to App engine or my code. could you guide on this please :)

Comment: @Ashu_FalcoN, Which step did you get that error? Can you share me your build pipeline settings and the whole build logs here?

Comment: I Didn't got any error in build and release pipeline. I got this error when I open the app engine url.

Comment: @Ashu_FalcoN The – in "npx serve –s" is incorrect. Please try "npx serve -s".