# Angular App CI from Azure Devop. After Realse successfull not showing from App Service

Tags: angular, azure, devops

I am creating a pipeline and deploying the angular application. After successful build and release  I can not show/visible the application app service. I am using FTP server azure provides a username and password.

some screenshot given below
[image]

[image]

Unexpectedly I can view my site

[image]

Answer (score 1):

We need to set server to handle routes of the node application .

- Set the startup command in
  Azure Portal => Configuration => General Settings

```cs
pm2 serve /home/site/wwwroot --no-daemon --spa
```

- Make sure the dist folder is under `wwwroot` directory
- Check in KUDU console whether all the files are deployed properly

***References taken from***

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59707804/deployed-angular-app-to-azure-web-app-but-showing-the-default-azure-page), [Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61122562/deployed-angular-dist-on-azure-web-app-showing-me-default-screen)